# Unexpected errror : npm WARN config shrinkwrap. Use the --package-lock setting instead

Tags: angular, npm-install, package.json, npm-package

I am getting this warning message though I am building the application successfully. This is the application I am migrating from angular 7 to 13 and getting this error during Angular version 10 to 11 migration. I don't have any npm-shrinkwrap.json and there is no package in the npm_modules for shrink-wrap. I only have package-lock.json

I have referred a couple of StackOverflow questions and google and still don't get any clear answer. Kindly help.

Comment: The answer is that you can't migrate directly from  7 to 13. You have to upgrade secuencially. from 7 to 8, 8 to 9 and so on... https://update.angular.io/

Comment: i know. i am doing migrate one major version at once. 7 to 8 , 8 to 9 .... 13..

Answer (score 1):

npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

to overcome this issue, running the command

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

globally and running the command

```
npm i npm@latest
```

in the project, the file helped me resolve the issue.